# Present viewController after touchUp GIDSignInButton()!

Tags: swift, xcode, mobile-development

I make a Google Auth for my App, but I don't know how to present a new viewController after touchup GIDSignInButton!

Here how I make GIDSignInButton:
   
`viewDidLoad (){
let googleBtn = GIDSignInButton()
googleBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 500 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 35)
view.addSubview(googleBtn)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code example that will present a second, programmatically generated view controller using a standard UIButton. Obviously, you could do the same with your GIDSignInButton:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController
    {
    override func viewDidLoad()
        {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 250, width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 35))
        button.setTitle("Go to VC2", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)

        }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton!)
        {
        let secondViewController = MySecondViewController()
        present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
        }
    }

class MySecondViewController:UIViewController
    {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    }
}
```

Note, however, that if you are presenting multiple views, you are advised to embed them in a Navigation Controller, as per Apple's [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html)